# Not able see the steps chart graph on Extent Report with C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, nunit, extentreports

I have configured Extent report with N unit C#. I am able to generate report but facing below issues

1. Report name is not generated with the name I specified .Code example below :

   ```
   var extent = new ExtentReports();
   var htmlreport = new ExtentHtmlReporter(@"D:\Test\Test\Test\Test\Reports\Firsttest.html");
   extent.AttachReporter(htmlreport);
   ```

The report is generating with a name as Dashboard.

Issue2: I can see only the test status Graph not the test steps Graph.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8LkE.png)

Something I was expecting like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FiQ2W.png)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Can someone please help?